# how to automate adding EBS volume to Elastic Beanstalk after managed updates

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, docker-volume

We're currently running an application hosted on Elastic Beanstalk using Docker, with additional EBS volume to store SQLite data. We have a few concerns regarding this setup

```
  We've enabled managed updates for minor and patch versions, and unchecked instance replacement, so updates will roll out automatically within the configured time frame.
```

- During the managed update(Minor and patch update) process, will it replace the EC2 instance?
- We don't require EC2 instance replacement, we only need minor and patch updates for the same EC2 instance..how can we achive this?
- If  EC2 instance replacement occurs whenever a minor or patch update is performed, how do we attach the additional EBS volume (SQLLITE Data)to be used by the Elastic Beanstalk Docker in the newly created EC2 instance. Is there an automated way to do this?

If there's a better solution available, we would appreciate any suggestions.